# How to access coefficient in return vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm solving a system of linear least squares using QR decomposition with Eigen, [as the documentation suggests](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html). I can't access individual coefficients in the solution vector using the parenthesis or bracket operators - which otherwise work fine for regular dense matrices. e.g. When accessing the first coefficient:

```
double coef = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b)[0];
```

I get the following compile error:

```
error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::solve_retval_base<Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::YOU_ARE_TRYING_TO_ACCESS_A_SINGLE_COEFFICIENT_IN_A_SPECIAL_EXPRESSION_WHERE_THAT_IS_NOT_ALLOWED_BECAUSE_THAT_WOULD_BE_INEFFICIENT' to function return type 'const double'

    return derived().coeff(index);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I access elements alone?

Comment: If you want to access individual elements and not operate on this or stream it, I would suggest using VectorXd.

Comment: @brettmichaelgreen Got it thanks.

Comment: Please place answers in an Answer block; not the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I solved this. There's an `.array()` call which transforms the expression type into a type that I can index into with the parenthesis or bracket operators.

Comment: It makes more sense to call `.eval()` to evaluate the expression into an actual `VectorXd` from which calling `[0]` or `(0)` is fine.

Comment: @ggael Could you explain the difference between `.eval()` and `.array()` and why it makes more sense to use `.eval()`? Thanks!

Comment: I guess that `.array()[0]` happens to work is merely by accident (it is not really a bug, but you should not rely on this behavior). `.eval()` is intended to mean "evaluate this into a temporary, before further processing"

Comment: And especially, if you access multiple elements of the result, you should explicitly store the result in a `VectorXd`